# magento 2 online customer data not showing

Tags: customer, magento2.2.3

In my instance when I try to check the now online customers the customerid, email and names columns are not showing. Can anyone help me with this[image]

Answer (score 0):

it is not shoving customer id, email, and names because they are visitors not a customers so there is no information like customer id, email, and name available for visitors

Comment: Or better known as a `guest` customer

Comment: yes the guest customers